# Any syntax sugar for instancinating an object with properties coming from IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#

I'm instantiating an object with properties coming from a IEnumerable. The straightforward way is

```
IEnumerable<string> source = ...
var instance = new X(
    source.First(), 
    source.Skip(1).First(), 
    source.Skip(2).First(),
    ...
);
```

Where `X` is a class with a constructor that takes a number of parameters.

This works, but it feels like this is a common scenario (for example fetching data using a generic storage layer and instantiating a specific record type) that there *should* be a cleaner way.

I considered making a list using a `.ToList()` and then access the properties using the indexer, but that evaluates the whole Enumerable which I don't feel is warranted here.

Is there a cleaner approach? I was imagining an Enumerator approach that would allow me to `.MoveNext()` & `.Current` approach, that would allow me O(1) access and no unnecessary allocations -- but with some syntax sugar to make that pretty

Comment: what is the `X` constructor signature? what are we looking at here? if this is a `params string[]` would `source.Take(theMaxNumber).ToArray()` work?

Comment: you can maybe create a method to pass parameters via `activator.createinstanc<T>` See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___

Comment: Note: `.Skip(n).First()` etc is not free - depending on what `source` is, this could be pretty expensive when performed multiple times

Comment: are you re-implementing an ORM here or what is the actual goal?

Comment: btw.: more "straightforward" would be to make an array first and access the elements via indexer: `var instance = new X(source[0], source[1])`, which will prevent multiple iterations on the same collection.

Comment: Right. I have considered the array/list approach but it left me wondering. And I realize the .Skip(n).First() approach is not free. I was after a Enumerator approach that would allow me to MoveNext&Current approach, that would allow me O(1) access and no unnecessary allocations -- but with some syntax sugar to make that pretty

Comment: Also note that `source.First(), source.Skip(1).First(), source.Skip(2).First()` is equivalent to `source.ElementAt(0), source.ElementAt(1), source.ElementAt(2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to take the first N values from the series, for some value of N.

If the `X(...)` takes a `params string[]`, then you can just use `source.Take(N).ToArray()`; since we'll be building the array *anyway*, this has no particular additional overhead.

If the `X(...)` takes `N` separate `string` parameters, then you do need to unroll it, but iterating the sequence multiple times is awkward. It may be ugly, but I'd probably use something custom here:

```cs
string a, b, c;
using (IEnumerator<string> iter = source.GetEnumerator())
{
    a = iter.Next();
    b = iter.Next();
    c = iter.Next();
}
return new X(a, b, c);

static class Utils
{
    public static T Next<T>(this IEnumerator<T> source)
    {
        if (!source.MoveNext()) Throw();
        return source.Current;

        static void Throw() => throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing element from sequence");
    }
}
```

---

You could also move the constructor inside the `using`, if you don't mind extending the sequence living a little longer (into the constructor invoke):

```cs
using IEnumerator<string> iter = source.GetEnumerator();
return new X(iter.Next(), iter.Next(), iter.Next());
```

Comment: iter.Next() was exactly what I was hoping for, but I do not recall the Next method - just the MoveNext method and Current property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=net-7.0). Having to combine them makes it useless for this usecase, but perhaps writing my own Next extension method is a reasonable cost

Comment: @DavidBožjak indeed, there is no `Next` method - but as shown: it isn't hard to add

Comment: I'm sorry I realize that I phrased my comment very clumsily. I tried to edit it but just missed the 5 minute cutoff. Anyway, yes, I agree, adding the extension method Next brings me to a decent looking solution, thank you for suggesting that!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters via `activator.createinstanc<T>`
See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Age = age;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<object> constructorArgs = new List<object>() { "David", "Božjak", 30 };
        Person p = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person), constructorArgs.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine($"{p.FirstName} {p.LastName} is {p.Age} years old.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is *true*, but reflection seems overkill here